# How to launch (create job or update job) at Google Cloud Run with cron schedule and container overides

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a process at google cloud that will launch multiple cloud run job with different sets of env variables to clean up the google storage old data (deeply nested and very large number of folders).

Due to the time they run, it is better for me to schedule them in different time in order not to slow down the performance.

```
try:
    
    run_job_client = run_v2.JobsClient()

    job = run_v2.Job()
    job.template.template.max_retries = 1187

    run_name="projects/" + PROJECT_ID + "/locations/" + JOB_REGION \
        + "/jobs/" + CALL_JOB    

    override_spec = {
        'container_overrides': [
            {
                'env': [
                    {'name':'TARGET_FILE', 'value':TARGET_FILE},
                    {'name':'SEQUENCE_NUMBER', 'value':SEQUENCE_NUMBER},
                    {'name':'PROJECT_CODE', 'value':PROJECT_CODE},

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    
    job_request = run_v2.RunJobRequest(
        name=run_name,
        overrides=override_spec
    )

    run_job_client.run_job(request=job_request)    
    print('I delete the folder') 
except:
    print('I failed to delete')
```

I am a beginner in gcloud and python. I understand I can launch run_v2.RunJobRequest to launch a job with new var setting, but I do not how to schedule this launch with a cron time to start. Any idea to can I schedule this RunJobRequest with a specific start time?

A second question, which I have spent sometimes on but not getting anywhere, so just try to see if anyone can help. To solve the above need, I tried to explore the use of run_v2.CreateJobRequest and see if I can create a new job with and then use scheduler to schedule it.

The sample [code](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/run/latest/google.cloud.run_v2.services.jobs.JobsClient#google_cloud_run_v2_services_jobs_JobsClient_create_job) here mentioned about accessing the container, I have the container already on storage, but there is not option to point that container at

```
    request = run_v2.CreateJobRequest(
        parent="parent_value",
        job=job,
        job_id="job_id_value",
    )
```

any idea what is the correct method of using run_v2.CreateJobRequest?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't in the exact right way. Cloud Run Jobs executes job, no more. If you want a scheduler, you need to use a scheduling service, like [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/).

Then, it's no so difficult:

- Create as [many scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs-on-schedule) you need for your clean up
- Call the [Job Override API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.jobs/run) and set the corresponding parameters in the JSON
- Set the correct [security parameters](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth) in the Cloud Run scheduler to be able to invoke the Cloud Run job service

---

That's being said, I also wondering about your design. You can call aggressively Cloud Storage, you just need to stay in the [allowed quotas](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas), and I see none about the concurrent requests (or number of requests per minutes)

Your slowness can come from the object distribution (if the object keys are sequential, all the object use the same node in the Cloud Storage cluster and you create a saturation, a bottleneck, on this node; also named hotspot)

Last but not least, you can have parallel tasks in Cloud Run Jobs. Imagine you have a list of bucket/prefix to delete, let say 20, you can run a Cloud Run Job with 5 tasks (instance) in parallel. Each instance has an env var that represent the [total number of task and the current task index](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#jobs-env-vars) of the current instance. Like that, you can calculate, at startup, which subset of the list the current instance must process.

A simple way to execute multiple runs in a single job

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guillaume,  will try. For your question about my clean up, those are google earth engine outdated maps down to 30 meters. I tried just to loop through a normal size map to count the nested item, it already takes 4 hours for a not-so-big area. I tried use blob delete and I never know it the task has been completed or not. Any insight about blob delete on top level can actually delete the whole "folder" for a larger size map on storage (know it is not a folder)?

Comment: Oh, I see. I have no tips to improve the deletion on Cloud Storage, but maybe a workaround. Are the data outdated regularly (for instance, every 30 days you need to clean up the data)?